# How to work with DELETE request and X-Auth-Token

Tags: http-headers, fiware, fiware-orion, http-delete, fiware-wilma

I want DELETE operation be allowed only after authentication/authorization process. I tried to do a DELETE operation passing an X-Auth-Token, but I got this: The status of this operation is: 400 Some error occurred!
    `{"error":"BadRequest","description":"Orion accepts no payload for GET/DELETE requests. HTTP header Content-Type is thus forbidden"}`

I did this with GET request, without problem, but it is not working for DELETE.

```
headers = {'X-Auth-Token': token}
s = Session()  
request = Request('DELETE', DELETE_URL + entity_id, headers=headers)
prepped = request.prepare()
del prepped.headers['Content-Length']
r = s.send(prepped)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, like @fgalan told in previous comments. A fix was made at PEP Proxy Wilma, as it can be seen [here](https://github.com/ging/fiware-pep-proxy/commit/96c1822827bdd4bd61ff66e795a913c37c2b915f)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the content-type header as suggested by the error message.

Comment: But I'm not passing content-type header; only the x-auth-token.

Comment: Maybe your programming framework is adding Content-Type header  without noticing it? It would be great to "capture" the HTTP request on the wire and ensure which actual headers are there.

Comment: I think its weird, because without the x-auth-token the DELETE works fine. I am using Python:

    r = requests.delete(DELETE_URL + entity_id, headers={'X-Auth-Token': token})

Comment: Anyway, I captured the request. Here it is:
== DELETE / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.11.0
X-Auth-Token: txDUAojkQtnbGudM5wgMOggQ4GHmat
Content-Length: 0

Comment: It seems to be a "caracteristic" of python requests module. For example, you can try with `curl <url> -X DELETE` and will see that `Content-Length: 0` is not included; Orion will not response with an error in this case. I'd recommend to post a question is SOF aksing how to remove `Conent-Lenght: 0` in delete() method for python requests module.

Comment: @fgalan , I removed the Content-Length in my request: 
 ` == DELETE / HTTP/1.1 
   Host: localhost 
   Accept-Encoding: identity 
   X-Auth-Token: KoryydIwZEi5oRIpQwqsPwqi14iRhq `

But I am still getting the same error: {"error":"BadRequest","description":"Orion accepts no payload for GET/DELETE requests. HTTP header Content-Type is thus forbidden"}

Comment: In oder to reproduce the case, could you edit your question post in order to include the exact code (in Python) you are using to generate the request without Content-Length, please? Thanks!

Comment: Done, @fgalan . The code is in the question. Thanks.

Comment: I have tested with an (almost) identical version of your python code and in my case I'm getting the right result: https://gist.github.com/fgalan/1957d528bf356c26d84cedb735512f06 (i.e. I'm getting 404 due to the entity doesn't exist in my system but the important point is that error about payload is not taking place). Could you try to reproduce the *exact* same steps in order to see potential differences, please? Which Orion version are you using (I'm using 1.6.0 + some additional changes in master branch, but the behavious shouldn't change with regards plain 1.6.0)?

Comment: @fgalan , I am also using Orion 1.6.0. Now, I did a direct DELETE test to Orion, without IdM+PEP. It worked fine: "The status of this operation is: 204 OK! Successful operation!"

I am suspecting the 'problem' is with the redirecting of PEP, because when I tested again with it, I received the error message one more time: "The status of this operation is: 400 Some error occurred!
{"error":"BadRequest","description":"Orion accepts no payload for GET/DELETE requests. HTTP header Content-Type is thus forbidden"}"
Could you test with IdM+PEP also?
Thanks.

Comment: Which PEP implementation are you using? Wilma or Steelskin?

Comment: Wilma, @fgalan.

Comment: After moving the issue to PEP Wilma development team, it seems there was an issue preventing that operation to work. It has been fixed today (see commit https://github.com/ging/fiware-pep-proxy/commit/96c1822827bdd4bd61ff66e795a913c37c2b915f). Could you update your Wilma installation and test again, please? Thx!